# An idiom/ idioms for a person who spends too much time on the cellphone?

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

Do we have any idioms for a person who spends too much time on the cellphone?

As we call a person who watches television a lot, a couch potato, or a person who spends large amounts of leisure or working time operating a computer, a mouse potato.

If there is any, I would appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually don't care if a person spends too much time on the phone. Call them

> a [smart]phone zombie
>
> a [smart]phone addict
>
> a cellcoholic *([a person addicted to cell phone usage](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cellcoholic))*
>
> a nomophobe *(I love it, it stands for [no-mobile-phone-phobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomophobia))*

But when we chat with that person and they repeatedly look at their phone (and miss a good part of what we say), it's annoying. We can call them

> a phubber *(derived from [phubbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phubbing))*

Answer (score 2):

Never heard “mouse potato” before but I like it! I guess you could extend this to “phone potato”? That is not a known expression, though. Probably *phone addict* is the best phrase for this.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who's always on their phone posting on social media and snap chatting is called a **Millennial**!!!

> Look at that guy on his phone all day he's such a **Millennial**.

That's a nice alternative for **phone addict** Millennials are very attached to their phones. Phone addiction is one of their strongest traits.

**Millennial**:denoting people reaching young adulthood in the early 21st century.